# CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext)

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

So far I have a drawing. I have different color buttons but I am not sure how to change the colors of them. I have all the RGB color codes but how do I make it so with an IBAction, it changes the  `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`

**.h:**

```
@interface GameScreen : UIViewController {

    BOOL mouseSwiped;
    float lineWidth;
    CGPoint lastPoint;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage;
}
@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "GameScreen.h"
#import "DoodlePicViewController.h"
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation GameScreen

@synthesize theimageView,choosePhoto, takePhoto;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lineWidth = thickness.value;

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lineWidth);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;



}



- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];


    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lineWidth);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}


@end
```

I'm really trying to figure it out but I am stuck ☹

Comment: So you've the drawing working but you want to vary it based on user input which is probably based on a couple of buttons right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a slider as the value of it is fromm 0 to 1. And you can get the values of 3 sliders, then pass them to the CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), without IB you can do it as well. I don't think IB is a good thing.